# How to call a Java method in PHP using php JavaBridge?

Tags: tomcat, php-java-bridge

I am a beginner. I want to call a java method from php. Am using Apache Tomcat server and Java-bridge. I have helo.java and its class file in sample.php am trying to call a method from java file.

helo.java

```
public class Helo
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.out.println("Hellooo");
          Helo a = new Helo();
          a.show();
      }
     public static void show()
     {
         System.out.println("java function");
     }          
  }
```

sample.php

```
<?php 
    require_once("java/Java.inc");
    $obj = Java("Helo");
    echo $obj; // this prints 'class Helo'        
    $obj->show(); // here is the ERROR 
....
?>
```

> ERROR:-
>   HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[c:Helo]]->show. Cause: php.java.bridge.NoSuchProcedureException: static show().

Please help me am stuck with this. thank you.

Comment: Hi did you find any solutions to this?